# While using Lombok 1.18.32 with java 17 it gives error that The type Lombok.Setter and Lombok.Setter is not accessible

Tags: java, lombok

[screen shot error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmtpK.png)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JtF4P.png)

Lombok version 1.18.32 is compatible with Java 8, but  encounter errors when attempting to use it with Java 17, despite having installed it in Eclipse.

Lombok 1.18.32 ->It is working with java 1.8 but while working with java 17 it gives error,I have installed Lombok in eclipse.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.